# use vim navigation and search commands in tmux terminal view mode

Tags: vim, tmux

Is there a way to use vim in tmux terminal output?

For example, I want to use `500j` to move 500 lines up instead of manually scrolling in vim using `Ctrl+a` +`[`

Comment: Do you mean `500k` or "down"? Since `500k` (or `500j`) is a valid navigation command in `less`, would a valid solution involve piping the output to `less` to navigate it the way you want, or do you want something that works with `tmux` in the console in general?

Comment: This question could be clearer - I suspect you mean to say that you would like to use vim key-bindings in the tmux window output, when vim is not running?

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for this config?

```
❯ grep mode-keys ~/.tmux.conf
set-window-option -g mode-keys vi
```